# Facebook Approval Rejection - pages_messaging_subscriptions

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

My Bot is rejecting from last 1 month with only reason everytime (pages_messaging_subscriptions)

MY BOT IS ABOUT FLOWERS , & FLOWERS CATEGORIES  . User can search flowers by categories, sort flowers by price and color.

In my previous discussion with facebook Support Team , i got the reply that i have to pay $99 for Customer Matching Fees for the Bot  so that Messages  Subscriptions can be approved  . I am ready to pay for it but still payment is invisible . I have a Company and PAGE setup from USA

I already setup Business Account with same Page and Developer but still i am not getting any CM Fees   .

Now i am not get any reply from Facbook support Team from last 7 Days

Can anyone help me out on this .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The currently defined three use cases/categories for subscription messaging are very narrow. If they say that what you are trying to send doesn’t fit any of them, then that’s just how it is. _“MY BOT IS ABOUT FLOWERS , & FLOWERS CATEGORIES . User can search flowers by categories, sort flowers by price and color.”_ – and what part of that needs subscription messaging?

Comment: So can we sent our Bot without subscription messaging   ?

Comment: Are you _using_ subscription messaging …?

Comment: Yes ,  Is it possible that i can my bot with out  subscription messaging ? What do you think , our bot needs Subscription messages ?

Comment: That is a question only you can answer. How are we supposed to know what your bot needs?

Comment: subscription messaging is compulsory in every case .Can you suggest  me any link or video that says that we can sent Bot approval without  subscription messaging . Really thanks for your time

Comment: Why would that be _“compulsory in every case”_ …?